# Google Endpoints JWT Limited JWT claims pass-thru

Tags: azure, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Is there a way to request specific JWT Claims to show up in the "X-Endpoint-API-UserInfo" header in a Google Cloud Endpoints oauth scenario?

As background, I have successfully had Google Cloud Endpoints validate my JWT token from Azure Oauth, however the data passed through in the header by Google Cloud Endpoints is limited and does not adequately contain enough information from the original Claims.

The claims provided by Azure can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code.

For example

`{
 "aud": "2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e",
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/7fe81447-da57-4385-becb-6de57f21477e/",
 "iat": 1388440863,
 "nbf": 1388440863,
 "exp": 1388444763,
 "ver": "1.0",
 "tid": "7fe81447-da57-4385-becb-6de57f21477e",
 "oid": "68389ae2-62fa-4b18-91fe-53dd109d74f5",
 "upn": "frank@contoso.com",
 "unique_name": "frank@contoso.com",
 "sub": "JWvYdCWPhhlpS1Zsf7yYUxShUwtUm5yzPmw_-jX3fHY",
 "family_name": "Miller",
 "given_name": "Frank"
}.`

However, Google Cloud Endpoints only returns 3 fields (issuer, id, and email) as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users.

As you can see, there is misalignment in the fields, and perhaps some fields that would be valuable to have access to in the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, `X-Endpoint-API-UserInfo` won't contain any additional info from claims than those documented (i.e. issuer, id, and email), however, the original JWT token itself is passed-through, so you can still extract the additional claims form there.

Comment: How do I access the original JWT token?

Comment: Sorry. Ignore my question. I got it myself. The payload in the JWT is just a base64 encoded string and can be easily decoded.